# What is the largest a wheeled or tracked vehicle could get?

Tags: engineering, megastructures, vehicles

What is the largest that we could make a wheeled or tracked vehicle with modern technology?

Comment: [5 second Google search](https://axleaddict.com/commercial-vehicles/What-is-the-Largest-Vehicle-in-the-World-5-Monstrously-Massive-Machines). Also, [real world questions are allowed](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6161/40609) but only with a world building context. (See [this great answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8076/40609).)

Comment: What are the requirements of the vehicle?  Bulldozer, crane, troop carrier, weapons platform?  What terrain does it need to be able to cross?  Or is it just a very expensive Guiness World Records contender?

Comment: Fun: [*The Big Bus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bus) (1976)

Comment: @JBH The question asks for the largest that could be made, not the largest that currently exists.

Comment: Another interesting contender outside of the mining space is NASA's [crawler transporter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crawler-transporter).

Comment: Ahh yes, the intent @SurpriseDog points to is interesting. Usually with large vehicles they are trying to move something heavy, so they themselves must be pretty heavy. But if you just want to make something big, you could try using lighter materials and construction, maybe inspired by aerospace engineering and get something bigger that would be useless.

Comment: Only constraint is money

Comment: Note : we could only answer such a question by building such a vehicle, as it's otherwise just an* opinion* (off-topic) as to whether any proposed vehicle size could in actual fact be built (unless we're already built it).

Comment: @Kilisi: And space.  I don't think it'd count as a wheeled/tracked vehicle if it overlaps the edges of your continent :-)

Comment: The Apollo mission to the moon had a vehicle. I'm not sure how much a Saturn booster massed...

Comment: @SurpriseDog I'm sorry, but what's the difference? In the mining world, if they could make bigger they would, because every ounce of ore that can be moved in bulk is profit. This is a much bigger issue than materials science - it involves many engineering skills, the geology of the ground the object will operate upon, the capacity for humanity to repair the machine... We humans are constantly striving to step over the next line and the extremes of today are often exactly that - the best we can do with the technology available to us.

Comment: @JBH In the mining world they would make the most cost effective machine, not the largest. Going larger means increased trouble with transportation and logistics. The square cube law means that it will require exponentially more material to produce a machine that's twice as large. I see this as a "hard science" question that asks what the limits of material science are.

Comment: @SurpriseDog Yes they would - as big a machine as they ground can hold that allows them to make a profit. But the square-cubed law is a terrible best-case analysis. The ground the machine is on, the nature of the differential, the capacity of motors. This is much more complex than saying "we can throw this much metal at it! Wow that's big!" Which is why the reference to the largest machines is valid. The OP's not asking for an immovable monument. The limits are not simply materials science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Giant powered axle**

Build two copies of the [world's largest ferris wheel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Roller_(Ferris_wheel)), each at 550ft high. Remove the cabins so they can roll on the rims. Attach them together with an axle long enough so they don't tip over (maybe 400ft). Then suspend a propeller aircraft engine from each end of the axle. You can steer like with a bulldozers treads: activate just the left engine to turn right, just the right to turn left, both to go forward. Prop engines can go in reverse too. Finally hang a cockpit from the middle of the axle.

It's big. It can probably be made to cruise over salt flats. Likely not good for much else.

Could you get something bigger in theory? Not sure.